# Obtaining coordinates from center of grid squares (research tools)

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I have a grid from research tools saved as shapefile. I want to display the center coordinate of each grid square in the attribute table.

Comment: Just use `add geometry attributes` under `vector->geometry tools`.

Comment: @Erik with polygons, add geometry attribute will add the area and the perimeter, but not the centroids X and Y

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I first thought that your squares were polygons. If they are lines, you need to convert the lines to polygons (vector > geometry tools > Lines to polygon) , then you can apply the method below (for polygons)

In the attribute table, you can compute the X and Y coordinates of the centroid (=the point at the center of the grid square) using the field calculator. The explicit (for X, but of course it also works fo Y) syntax is

```
x(centroid($geometry))
```

but in fact you can use the shortcut

```
x($geometry)
```

[image]

Comment: This seemed to give me the center point for each line in the grid, rather than the center of each grid square.

Comment: If you have a grid of lines, but want to know the center of each 'cell' of a grid, you must first convert your grid of lines into a polygon.

Comment: If your grid is regular, you can may be just add manually half the width of the grid : x($geometry) + (Width/2)

Comment: @Christophe good idea if the grid is regular and the lines are parallel with the x/y axes, but this might also require some clean up first: split lines at each intersection and select only the vertical lines

Answer (score -2):

I polygonized the grid, then used centroid.

Strangely lines to polygon did not work, but polygonize did.